# Using conditions as a hash for joined tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am using Rails 2.3.5 and is wondering if it is possible to rewrite this query using conditions as a hash.

```
joined_deals = Deal.all :joins => :shops
                        :conditions => ["shops.name = ?", name]
```

to something like `:conditions => {"shops.name" => name}`. Is it possible in Rails 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes, it is possible in Rails 2.**

For more information, refer here: 
[specifying-conditions-on-the-joined-tables](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.8/active_record_querying.html#specifying-conditions-on-the-joined-tables)